# Byte Buddy Advice breaks Eclipse debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bytecode, byte-buddy

I have used net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice to add code before and after suitably annotated methods, to start and stop timers. The modified classes are manually loaded into the target class loader before their originals can be referenced, thereby supplanting them. I'm using OSGi (Equinox).

Pretty sweet but when I stop the Eclipse (Photon 4.8.0) debugger on a breakpoint in the target method, the Variables view shows only:

> com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got error code in reply:35 occurred
>   retrieving 'this' from stack frame.

Is this inevitable and unavoidable? Kinda ruins my use-case if this renders instrumented code undebuggable :(

(I have disabled the option "Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; may be slow".)

### Example

I believe I may have found some issues with the generated bytecode.

Class to be instrumented:

```
 1 package com.tom.test;
 2
 3 import com.tom.instrument.Instrumented;
 4 import com.tom.instrument.Timed;
 5
 6 @Instrumented(serviceType = "blah")
 7 public class Test {
 8
 9 @Timed
10 public void writeName() {
11   final String myLocal = "Tom";
12      System.out.println(myLocal);  
13   }
14
15 }
```

"Advice":

```
package com.tom.instrument;

import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.OnMethodEnter;

public class Instrumentation {

    @OnMethodEnter
    public static void onMethodEnter() {
        System.out.println("Enter");
    }

}
```

Call to Byte Buddy:

```
new ByteBuddy()
    .redefine(type, ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of(this.classLoader))
    .visit(Advice.to(Instrumentation.class)
    .on(isAnnotatedWith(Timed.class)))
    .make().saveIn(new File("instrumented"));
```

Result in javap:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
...

  public void writeName();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #19                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #40                 // String Enter
       5: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: goto          11
      11: ldc           #17                 // String Tom
      13: astore_1
      14: getstatic     #19                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      17: ldc           #17                 // String Tom
      19: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      22: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 11: 0
      line 12: 14
      line 13: 22
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
         11      12     0  this   Lcom/tom/test/Test;
         14       9     1 myLocal   Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

If I set a break point on line 11 of Test.java then the Eclipse Debug view says: `<unknown receiving type>(Test).writeName() line: 11`

And the Variables view says: `com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got error code in reply:35 occurred retrieving 'this' from stack frame.`

If I hack the bytecode changing 00 to 0B at 0x2A2 so the line number table looks like:

```
LineNumberTable:
  line 11: 11
  line 12: 14
  line 13: 22
```

Then everything is fine! And that kinda seems correct to me but I'm no expert here.

If I also use `@OnMethodExit` too then it's a bit more complicated. Add the following to `Instrumentation.class`:

```
@OnMethodExit
public static void onMethodExit() {
    System.out.println("Exit");
}
```

javap gives:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
...

  public void writeName();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #19                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #40                 // String Enter
       5: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: goto          11
      11: aload_0
      12: astore_1
      13: ldc           #17                 // String Tom
      15: astore_2
      16: getstatic     #19                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      19: ldc           #17                 // String Tom
      21: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      24: goto          27
      27: getstatic     #19                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      30: ldc           #42                 // String Exit
      32: invokevirtual #25                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      35: goto          38
      38: return
    LineNumberTable:
      line 11: 0
      line 12: 16
      line 13: 24
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
         13      14     1  this   Lcom/tom/test/Test;
         16      11     2 myLocal   Ljava/lang/String;
}
```

To fix this I have to update the line number table and the local variable table. Like this:

```
LineNumberTable:
  line 11: 13
  line 12: 16
  line 13: 24
LocalVariableTable:
  Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
     13      14     0  this   Lcom/tom/test/Test;
     16      11     1 myLocal   Ljava/lang/String;
```

Diff:
[image]

Maybe it's a bug the the Eclipse debugger expects `this` to always be in slot 0? Or maybe that's the way it should be. The error code 35 comes from the JVM though.

The reason why adding the exit advice changes the slots seem to be because it causes `ForInstrumentedMethod.Default.Copying` to be used instead of `Simple`. And they have different implementations of `variable()`.

Comment: See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531706#c4

Comment: Thanks. I had already seen not that bug but the post it links to. I have disabled the option "Show method result after a step operation (if supported by the VM; may be slow" in case it helped but it made no difference. Also, I have Eclipse 4.8.0 which should include the fix that seemed to result from the bug you linked.

Comment: Does the problem also occur when you apply the advice during build time using the Maven or Gradle plugin? If the byte code can be executed, I do not see how this can be an issue that is caused by Byte Buddy and in IntelliJ - which I use - I have not observed anything like that. Given these observations, I argue that this is a problem cause by the Eclipse debugger. Potentially, Byte Buddy messes up some meta data used for debugging, if you could build a reproduction, I can take a look and you might just submit this as a bug to Eclipse, too.

Answer (score 2):

See [Eclipse bug 531706](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531706):

The issue occurs when **not all classes have been instrumented**, see [comment #4 by Tobias Hirning](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531706#c4):

> ...
>
> Now I am also getting a clearer picture: The errors only appeared in
>   method invocations where the methods are in jar files. And I think
>   they were not instrumented.
>
> ...

The error **happens in the VM, not in Eclipse**. When Eclipse requests the variables via the debugging interface **error code `35` is returned instead of the values**. The change made due to the mentioned bug report is to ignore it, see [comment #7 by Till Brychcy (who made the change)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=531706#c7):

> ...
>
> I've been able to reproduce the problem and simply ignoring the
>   InternalException in this codepath improves the situation.
>
> You'll sometimes see a message about the error code 35 in the
>   variables view, but in general it seems to work.

**To avoid this issue, you have to instrument all classes.**

Comment: Thanks for your assistance; it is much appreciated. I see, perhaps there is a little more to that bug than I realised. However, I'm not running any agents. What it meant by instrument all classes? I only want to add the timing code to a small number of methods. So how would I instrument the rest? All classes referenced by the class I'm trying to debug? All classes in the bundle? All classes in the application? That would be millions of methods in thousands of JARs, many of which are third party libraries.

Comment: Ah, I have a new theory—or perhaps I have finally understood what you meant. Is it the case that Eclipse (JDT) is instrumenting all classes when I run in debug mode but that it never gets chance to instrument my dynamic ones. I see `-javaagent:../javaagent-shaded.jar` in the process command. Is there some way that I can get my dynamic classes instrumented?

Comment: If instrumentation is used incorrectly, it might happen that an error occurs inside the JVM when variables are requested via the [Java Debug Interface (JDI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/overview-summary.html#overview.description) from the JVM. The problem is probably caused by the way you build or run your application. Problems may also arise when using Byte Buddy with other code modifying frameworks, such as code coverage frameworks, AspectJ, Mockito, Lombok, etc. Can you give a minimal example of how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Maybe you will some hints in the Byte Buddy documentation (e. g. [Javadoc of ByteBuddyAgent](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.8.0/net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent.html)) or in some [Byte Buddy issue reports](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/issues) how to solve your issue.

Comment: It seems that javaagent-shaded.jar was a red herring. I tried manually running it's transformer over my new classes before injecting them but it didn't help. I think that is just for the Eclipse "Advanced source lookup" feature and, besides, that agent is not run when I launch my OSGi app, only on a minimal version that I prepared. I'll try to share that... Maybe the byte code I'm generating is bad in some way...

Comment: You could try to see if it makes a difference if the application is started outside of Eclipse and debugged remotely.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Eclipse to instrument all classes? I never had instrumentation problems in the past. I don't have any instrumentation setup for this project. I've only experienced this issue with a new class. I suppose I could try cleaning the entire project and seeing if that affects instrumentation

Comment: @committedandroider This issue was caused by a bug that has been fixed in the meantime. Please upgrade to Eclipse Photon (4.8) or higher. It is recommended to use the latest Eclipse version which is currently Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11).

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

Aha! All my fishing around looking to make a patch has lead me to find something that I wish I had found sooner.

- I can use `@OnMethodEnter(prependLineNumber = false)` to avoid the issue with the line numbers.
- And using `@OnMethodExit(backupArguments = false)` avoids the problem with the slots.

This is good news for me! However, presumably these are not the defaults for good reason. I don't yet understand if there are important negative consequences of using these options.

Comment: For future readers: If an exception is thrown in the enter advice and not captured; it will not carry a line number. Also, if you tried to capture the line number via an exception stack or the stack walker, it would not work without prepending the line number. If you do not backup the arguments, any reassignments of arguments within the instrumented method will become visible in the exit advice. Also, some languages and obfuscators mess up the local variables array and you might face instrumentation exceptions as a consequence.